# SQL query to find users with certain values in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

### Overview

I have two tables - `tmc_users` and `tmc_user_usergroup_map`.

In `tmc_users`, there is a list of `user_id`s and in `tmc_usergroup_map` each `user_id` can be associated with multiple `group_id`s.

I am trying to find all the `user_id`s who have a `group_id` of `12` but do **not** have a `group_id` of 17.

Each user can be a member of both.

### Current query

This is the query to get all the users associated with the `group_id` 12, which returns a total number of 1439 rows:

```
SELECT `id`, LTRIM(RTRIM(`name`)), COUNT(`id`) AS `total`
    FROM `tmc_users` u
    LEFT JOIN `tmc_user_usergroup_map` g
    ON u.`id` = g.`user_id`
    WHERE g.`group_id` = 12
    ORDER BY LTRIM(RTRIM(`name`)) ASC
```

### New query

This is what I've tried in order to filter out users who *also* are in the `group_id` 17:

```
SELECT `id`, LTRIM(RTRIM(`name`)), COUNT(`id`) AS `total`
    FROM `tmc_users` u
    LEFT JOIN `tmc_user_usergroup_map` g
    ON u.`id` = g.`user_id`
    WHERE g.`group_id` != 17
    AND g.`group_id` = 12
    ORDER BY LTRIM(RTRIM(`name`)) ASC
```

However, this returns the same number of rows - 1439 - whereas the actual number of users this should have is 1353.

How can I make this work in one single query?

Comment: `group_id` from which table?

Comment: `tmc_user_usergroup_map` g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT `id`, LTRIM(RTRIM(`name`)), COUNT(`id`) AS `total`
FROM `tmc_users` u
LEFT JOIN `tmc_user_usergroup_map` g
  ON u.`id` = g.`user_id`
WHERE g.`group_id` = 12 AND 
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM `tmc_user_usergroup_map` AS t
                 WHERE t.`user_id` = u.`id` AND t.`group_id` = 17)
ORDER BY LTRIM(RTRIM(`name`)) ASC
```